Are these craters on the moon during eclipse
can somebody confirm that what im looking at are craters on the moon? This was taken during the 2024 eclipse from illinois with my S24 ultra iso250 115mm -2.0ev F3.4 speed 1/10000. thanks


Beautiful photo! I can't confirm it myself but it certainly looks that way. Since the Moon is not a polished sphere but instgead quite rough, certainly some areas very close to the limb will still be at least very obliquely illuminated so it's geometrically possible. For confirmation all that's needed is for someone to run a simulator like Wtellarium to first see the exact topography near the lunar limb at that time, and then (if the software supports this) use realistic solar illumination to see if you can reproduce the same pattern.

those are likely either lens/filter issues, or poor seeing conditions, exaggerated by  the overexposure. They are not craters

@Topcode what factor so completely rules out any possibility that they could be reflections from topography?

@SupaD75 for more simulators see the answer to Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?

@uhoh Well, there are a few. For one, the moons illumination was roughly the same size as would be depicted in the image, a day after the eclipse, there is zero possibility that level of illumination could occur during the eclipse. And even if it did, the moon has a surface brightness about 400000 times less than the sun. there is most likely not a lens in existence, which can capture that level of difference directly adjacent, with no bloom.

@Topcode ok, sold.

The best evidence they are not craters is that other people's photos don't show them.

@Topcode i am not entirely convinced. Blooming mostly is a problem for ccd, yet cmos surpasses them in this regard and is meanwhile usually used. I can buy the Argument with the Illuminaten Area somewhat

As Greg Miller pointed out, no other person’s photo shows that. It’s probably just a camera artifact. I have a picture (of people) taken a few minutes after the eclipse where half is fine and the other half seems to be seen through (thin) fog. Electronic cameras are known to leave artifacts on some images sometimes.

I do apologize I did take through a filer. And I can't remember if I took through the eclipse glasses or a welding helmet lens. But either way with direct shadows behind the "craters" and the topography I still say craters

Could that be atmospheric distortion rather than lens/filter effects? The first thing I thought of from seeing this was the way an inferior mirage ripples due to the interface between the hot surface air and the cooler air above it...

@SupaD75 if you really believe they are craters, you should pull up a planetarium program and match up features in the photo to actual features on the moon and update the question or post the results as an answer below.  Also note how much of the moon's surface the planetarium program shows as illuminated.

Yes I did just that

From what I can see this bears are striking resemblance to my photo thoughts?](https://i.sstatic.net/MirDHKpB.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/MirDHKpB.jpg) 

There are lots of craters on the Moon :-) so it is not surprising to find an example that will match a grainy image. What you need to show is: (a) the orientation of the eclipse photo (celestial N, S, E, W), (b) an image of the Moon corrected for libration, (c) match the two. Since Mare Frigoris is near the N pole of the Moon, the craters near Frigoris would not be near the center of the cusp during the eclipse.


OK So yeah from this pic, exact time and date, I'm certainly not seeing the craters that I was hoping to see as in my pic. Was cool to think so anyway. Thank everyone for the help!

Can you please consolidate your answers into one? They make sense combined, but dont answer the question alone

Please consolidate your answer into one singular post. Multiple answer are written by same author only when there is a contradiction.
